# Switch between microphones in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04, pulseaudio, microphone, sound-recorder

I want to record sounds from my piano.

For this I have a jack cable that connects the piano with my laptop.

My laptop has an built-in microphone that I don't want to use it when recording from my keyboard.

So, I connected my piano with the laptop by jack cable. I have the following settings in input on Sounds:

[image]

If I connect my microphone from my phones the "Internal Microphone" changes to "Microphone", like in the screen shot:

[image]

This will capture the sounds from my phones microphone.

My question is: how can I set the latest setting when using my piano? I want to capture sounds from my piano, using the jack cable.

Maybe it's important to know that I can listen the sounds from piano in live mode, but I can't record them.

Update:

`pactl list sources` outputs this in the `Ports`:

#### Case 1

Piano is connected:

```
analog-input-microphone-internal: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900)
analog-input-microphone: Microphone (priority: 8700, not available)
```

#### Case 2

An external microphone is connected:

```
analog-input-microphone-internal: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900, not available)
analog-input-microphone: Microphone (priority: 8700, available)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to switch input sources, and settings for recordings we may install and run [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol].

#### Select recording source

Only after we had started recording with our recording application we can then select the device where we want to record from:

[image]

Choose *"Monitor of..."* device for recording the sound that plays from this device, or any other input source.

---

#### Select a duplex audio device

Alternatively we can switch to a duplex audio profile for our sound output device to allow simultaneous listening and recording from our audio output device.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for documented answer but unfortunately it still doesn't work. It can record from micrphone from phones, but not from piano. A fast reply + edit would be appreciated or if you can help me via chat... and then edit the final answer.

Comment: That's weird. With *"Monitor of..."*, or with a duplex profile you should be able to record anything that you can listen to. You say you can hear your piano?

Comment: Let's open a chat, and discuss there. I am glad that you are here, now. :)

Comment: I've opened here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9204/johnnys-room

Comment: Yes, I can hear my piano into the laptop.

Comment: In configuration tab I see only "Built-in Audio" item. What can I do to see the monitor?